# Duplicating a 2d matrix in matlab along a 3rd axis MANY times

Tags: matlab

I'm looking to duplication a 784x784 matrix in matlab along a 3rd axis. The following code seems to work:

```
mat = reshape(repmat(mat, 1,10000),784,784,10000);
```

Unfortunately, it takes so long to run it's worthless (changing the 10,000s to 1000 makes it take a few minutes, and using 10,000 makes my whole machine freeze up practically). is there a faster way to do this?

For reference, I'm looking to use mvnpdf on 10,000 vectors each of length 784, using the same covariance matrix for each. So my final call looks like

```
mvnpdf(X,mu,mat)  

%size(X) = (10000,784), size(mu) = (10000,784), size(mat) = 784,784,10000
```

If there's a way to do this that's not repeating the covariance matrix 10,000 times, that'd be helpful too. Thanks!

Comment: This is one of those cases where it might be faster to just use a for loop than to take the hit from that `repmat`. Most of the compute time is going to be used in the `mvnpdf` calculation so there's negligible speed benefit (and massive memory use) from doing that to your covariance matrix.

Comment: I've actually already written this with a for loop, and it still takes forever :(. This was my attempt to rewrite it to be more efficient, but I think you're right. mvnpdf is an expensive operation (i assume), so running it 10,000 times is probably going to be slow no matter what...

Comment: Thanks for that comment. You reminded me of the crux of what will speed up your code significantly, and I've posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a 784x784 matrix 10,000 times isn't going to take advantage of the vectorization in MATLAB, which is going to be more useful for small arrays. Avoiding a for loop also won't help too much, given the following:

The main speedup you can gain here is by computing the inverse of the covariance matrix once, and then computing the pdf yourself. The inverse of sigma takes O(n^3), and you are needlessly doing that 10,000 times.  (Also, the square root determinant can be precomputed.) For reference, the PDF of the multivariate normal distribution is computed as follows:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Properties

Better to just compute the inverse once, and then compute `z = x - mu` for each value, then doing `z'Sz` for each pdf value, and applying a simple function and a constant. But wait! You can vectorize that, too.

I don't have MATLAB in front of me, but this is basically what you need to do, and it'll run in an instant.

```
s = inv(sigma);
c = -0.5*log(det(s)) - (k/2)*log(2*pi);
z = x - mu;                   % 10000 x 784 matrix
ans = exp( c - 0.5 .* dot(z*s, z, 2) ); % 10000 x 1 vector
```

Comment: Duh! I'm so used to relying on built-in matlab functions, I forgot how to just do this the obvious way. I haven't tried this yet, but this sounds exactly like what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: OK. please feel free to check my math. I optimized things a bit according to the actual `mvnpdf` implementation.

Comment: shouldn't the 2 in front of log(det(s)) be a -1/2?

Comment: also, z*s*z' produces a 10000*10000 matrix. I think a for loop through all of the column vectors in z is a better way to do it.

Comment: Yes to the (-1/2), somehow I got the -1 confused with the inverse, and sorry about the `z*s*z'` thing, I updated with properly vectorized code. This is one part where you don't have to use a for loop :)

Answer (score 7):

For replication in more than 2 dimensions, you need to supply the replication counts as an array:

```
out = repmat(mat,[1,1,10000])
```

Comment: I've already run the code for smaller values (3,10,etc...), and the output is exactly what I want it to be.  Yours works too though, and it's cleaner (although now any faster unfortunately). Thanks!

Comment: Its the ones at the start that I never got. Very useful example, thank you.